# Adding multiple text boxes and drop list using jQuery and add each added form into database as single row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am creating a form to add patient history on medications. By that I mean, each patient have side effect on multiple drugs.

Here is the form:

```
 <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" style="color: #0090ff" align="center">
        Patient Medical History
      </div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="patient_medication">Medication</label>
            <fieldset class="form-group">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_medication" name="patient_medication" required>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <label for="patient_medication">Disease</label>
            <fieldset class="form-group">

            <select style="height:50px; color: #0090ff" class="form-control select" id="disease" name="disease">
              <option value="choose">Choose</option>
            </select>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <label for="patient_medication">Side Effect</label>
            <fieldset class="form-group">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="side_effect" name="side_effect" required>
          </fieldset>
        </div>

      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"  id="remove" name="remove"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;" id="add_more" name="add_more"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add More</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Sometimes, we need to add multiple history, so we need to click on Add More button to add another row of the previous form, and fill it.

Then I need to send all these data through AJAX to MySQL. So if I added 3 medical history on medication and their side effect, in database 3 rows should be added.

What I did for the first part is by using the code [from this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/curtisweeks/k4kanw6L/).
It work fine but it is not convenient to create 10 or more hidden forms and change their visibility by JavaScript and add the 10 forms into database even if they are empty.

How can I add more rows of the form and fill them and add them to database using JQuery and Ajax?

Comment: your js fiddle example not working properly

Comment: you should type inside the textbox then add another

Comment: the idea behind the fiddle that it's not relevant

Comment: I need to add text boxes dynamically